# Grainy still image even at 20,000 samples

Tags: rendering

[image: grain problem]

This is a Glass BSDR material with two thin area lights behind that are causing the grain. Seems crazy at 20,000 samples but I'm new to this so any intel would be much appreciated!

Here is the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CY5ucFPGJGROIK-r7XVHNEsETBWRrdje/view?usp=sharing

Cycles.
No Denoise (this just made it smudgy and worse).
No Noise Threshold.
No Time Limit.

Light Paths> Max Bounces>
Total: 36
Diffuse: 8
Glossy: 8
Transmission: 12
Volume 0
Transparent: 8

Answer (score 0):

I believe that It might be related to your shader settings.

Select the desired object, go to the *Shading* tab and try playing around with the *Roughness* values.

Keep in mind that it might not be related (only) to the base roughness, but to the other roughness parameters (in *Coat*, *Sheen*).

Also, it might be related to the mesh itself, double-check that.

Same as you, I am a new contributor here, so someone else might have better answers than me, however, I'd advise you to share your project file, so that someone more experienced can check, and help, if it comes to that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Blend file added. I think you're right about it having to do with the material.